# Is it wrong to use Assert.That (rather than Assume.That) with a [Theory]?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, theory

```
interface IPoint
{
    int X { get; }
    int Y { get; }
}

static bool CoincidesWith(this IPoint self, IPoint other); // implementation unknown
```

I want to write a NUnit test that verifies my assumption about the meaning of `CoincidesWith`:

> `self.CoincidesWith(other)` ⇔ (`self.X` = `other.X`) ∧ (`self.Y` = `other.Y`)

The following is the most succinct test I've been able to come up with so far:

```
[Theory]
void CoincidesWith_Iff_CoordinatesAreEqual(IPoint self, IPoint other)
{
    bool coordinatesAreEqual = (self.X == other.X && self.Y == other.Y);
    Assert.That(self.CoincidesWith(other) == coordinatesAreEqual);
}
```

My questions, in descending order of importance, are:

1. With `[Theory]`, is it considered wrong, or bad style, to use `Assert.That` instead of `Assume.That`? ([The documentation seems to suggest that the latter should be used in conjunction with `[Theory]`.](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5))
2. Is this case indeed more suitable for a `[Theory]` rather than a `[Test]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more thought, I've come to the conclusion that there is nothing wrong with my above solution.

> *Is this case indeed more suitable for a `[Theory]` rather than a `[Test]`?*

If the implementation for the `CoincidesWith` method were available for inspection (e.g. as source code), or at least well-documented, then there would be no need to make assumptions — I could simply look up what I need to know. In that case, a `[Test]` — or, as [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) calls tests, a `[Fact]` — would seem more appropriate.

But since I have no access to the implementation for `CoincidesWith`, and the documentation is insufficient, I do need to make some assumption, or `[Theory]`, about the general working of the method.

> *With `[Theory]`, is it considered wrong, or bad style, to use `Assert.That` instead of `Assume.That`?*

No. It's just another tool to be used, and neither less nor more appropriate than `Assert.That`.

In the context of a `[Theory]`, `Assume.That` would seem to be the right means of putting additional constraints on the supplied `[Datapoints]`, while verifying the actual assumption (using those datapoints that make it past `Assume.That`) is left to `Assert.That`.

An example can illustrate this. Let's try to write a test for this assumption:

> Given an even integer `a` and an odd integer `b`, their product `a * b` is even.

Testing if `a * b` is even only makes sense once the preconditions are met. If `a` is not an even integer, or `b` is not an odd integer, the test should neither succeed nor fail; it should be inconclusive. And that's exactly what `Assume.That` helps achieve. The actual test, however, is left to `Assert.That`:

```
[Theory]
void GivenAnEvenIntegerAndAnOddInteger_ProductIsAnEvenInteger(int a, int b)
{
    Assume.That(a.IsEven());
    Assume.That(b.IsOdd());
    // note: the type system already ensures that `a` and `b` are integers.
    int product = a * b;
    Assert.That(product.IsEven());
    // note: the theory doesn't require `product` to be an integer, so even
    // if the type system didn't already assert this, we would not test for it.
}

[Datapoints]
int[] integers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

static bool IsEven(this int integer) { … }
static bool IsOdd(this int integer) { … }
```